# What is the correct way to create locale -object in Java (for instance Finnish)

Tags: java, jsf-2, localization, locale, facescontext

Could someone tell me why locale Finnish is not working and the rest are?

```
private static Map<String,Object> countries;
    private static Locale finnishLocale = new Locale("fi", "FI");

static{
    countries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    countries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH); //label, value
    countries.put("French", Locale.FRENCH);
    countries.put("German", Locale.GERMAN);
    countries.put("Finnish", finnishLocale); <---------- Not working!
}

public void setLocaleCode(String localeCode) {


                this.localeCode = localeCode;
                updateLocale(localeCode);          


        }


public void updateLocale(String newLocale){

        String newLocaleValue = newLocale;

        //loop country map to compare the locale code
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : countries.entrySet()) {

               if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue());

              }
               }

        }
```

I mean that the locale which I created with New-clause is not working. I can't explain it better, because I thought that locale implemented like that is similar Locale-object than for instance Locale.GERMAN? My software doesn't do anything else than update locale ja Faces context. There is no exceptions. Sorry if the q is stupid. Everything else is working, I mean German, English etc and the program updates the locale and Faces context.

I would be very much appreciated if you answer the question, I am lost (again)
Sami

Comment: "*not workin*" is not a compiler or runtime error I have ever seen.

Comment: @house_no_name, I am surprised you have not heard about "NotWorkingException", it is the parent class of Exception, Error, UserStupidity, EndOfWorld et al.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `updateLocale()` method seems to be the culprit. You're comparing `Locale#toString()` against `newLocale`. The `Locale` constants have all only the language set, not the country. `Locale.ENGLISH.toString()` for example returns `"en"` while `new Locale("fi", "FI").toString()` returns `"fi_FI"`. That can only mean that your `newLocale` variable actually contains `"en"`, `"fr"`, `"de"` and `"fi"`. The first three would match the constants, but the latter wouldn't match the `finnishLocale`, because you're comparing against its `toString()` instead of `getLanguage()`.

To fix your problem, *either* change

```
private static Locale finnishLocale = new Locale("fi", "FI");
```

to

```
private static Locale finnishLocale = new Locale("fi");
```

*or*, better, change `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, Locale>` and then change

```
if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){
```

to

```
if(entry.getValue().getLanguage().equals(newLocaleValue)){
```

All with all, this map loop is rather clumsy. If the `newLocale` is a server side controlled value, just do `viewRoot.setLocale(new Locale(newLocale))` instead.

Comment: Thaks a lot, kiitos paljon! FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(localeCode)); That was so tidy and clean solution that I am shamed :) From 20 lines of code to one...There is so much to learn. Sami

Answer (score 2):

You have an error somewhere else since this works:

```
public class Runner01 {
private static Map<String,Object> countries;
private static Locale finnishLocale = new Locale("fi", "FI");

static{
    countries = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
    countries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH); //label, value
    countries.put("French", Locale.FRENCH);
    countries.put("German", Locale.GERMAN);
    countries.put("Finnish", finnishLocale); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : countries.entrySet() ) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=>" + entry.getValue().toString());
    }
}


}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I'll try to solve it. I am using the setter straight from JSF-page like that:
       <p:submenu label="Languages">
                        <p:menuitem value="English" ajax="false" actionListener="#{language.setLocaleCode('en')}"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="German" ajax="false" actionListener="#{language.setLocaleCode('de')}"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="French" ajax="false" actionListener="#{language.setLocaleCode('fr')}"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Finnish" ajax="false" actionListener="#{language.setLocaleCode('fi')}"/>